# Run Files and Programs according to custom checkboxes after clicking on Finish Button in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have created some custom checkboxes in the finished page of Inno Setup.
For example launching an app, opening a text file etc.

I need when the user clicks on the finish button I check those checkboxes and do whatever that is needed. How can I do such a thing in Inno Setup?

Here is the code:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
       Launch := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
       Launch.Parent := WizardForm;
       Launch.Left := WizardForm.ClientWidth - 350;
       Launch.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
       Launch.Width := 120;
       Launch.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
       Launch.Caption := 'Launch';
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`NextButtonClick` event handler](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick), test if your checkbox is checked and act accordingly.

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  Path: string;
  Message: string;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    if Launch.Checked then
    begin
      Path := ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.exe');
      if ExecAsOriginalUser(Path, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode) then
      begin
        Log('Executed MyProg');
      end
        else
      begin
        Message := 'Error executing MyProg: ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode);
        MsgBox(Message, mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the checkbox state:

```
if (Launch.Checked = True) then
begin
// checkbox is checked
end
else
begin
// Checkbox is unchecked
end;
```

The best place is to use **function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;**
however in that case you need to make your checkbox a global variable (so it is accessible).