# Run application after click on the Finish button (not after install)

Tags: inno-setup

I have a setup for installing my application, and I need to run the application after successfully installing. I used `postinstall` to do this.

but it shows a checkbox and the user can uncheck it. I need to run the application without asking because of it kinda service which needs to runs at startup. if the user unchecked it he needs to restart the PC to launch.

So I can use the `Filename: "{app}\myapp.exe"` code without any flags in the `Run` section to launch the application but the problem is, It runs immediately after installing not after the finish button clicked.

The first issue is my application has an instruction window. it shows up at the launch so the setup window goes to the back. And the second issue is my application does not allow terminating unless uninstall becouse it need to run in the background. Setup waiting to process end to finish.

Is there any way to run the application after the finish button click in inno setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplifying the answer from [Run Files and Programs according to custom checkboxes after clicking on Finish Button in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55001388/850848), you can use a code like this:

```pascal
[Code]

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  Path, Msg: string;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    Path := ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.exe');
    if ExecAsOriginalUser(Path, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode) then
    begin
      Log('Executed MyProg');
    end
      else
    begin
      Msg := 'Error executing MyProg - ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode);
      MsgBox(Msg, mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Replace [`ExecAsOriginalUser`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser) with [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec), if you want to run the program with elevated/Administrator privileges (if the installer uses them at all).

Answer (score 0):

Add `code` section to your script like this:

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
end;
```

It will be triggered only on a success installation.

Use `ExecAsOriginalUser` instead of `Exec` if you don't want the exe run as admin.

Comment: Unfortunately there are edge cases when `CurStepChanged(ssDone)` is (imo incorrectly) called even when the installation does not finish successfully.